# How can I add per-target UIAppFonts to a shared Info.plist file at build time

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I have a project where multiple targets share a single `Info.plist` file. Simple target-specific strings are inserted into the file at build time by way of `${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES}` and that's fine.

However, I want to specify per-target values for the `UIAppFonts` array and the same strategy does not work. What's the best way to insert values for this array at build time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution here was to create a target-specific `fonts-target.plist`, containing just an array of font files for the particular target. Then I use `PListBuddy` in a Run Script Build Phase to inject that plist into the Info.plist file at build time. It's a little finicky because `PListBuddy` is very particular about how you can use its options on containers:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :UIAppFonts" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :UIAppFonts array" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Merge ${SRCROOT}/Resources/Target-Specific/fonts-${TARGET}.plist :UIAppFonts" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
```

Three commands because:

- You can't `Merge` if the thing *doesn't* exist.
- You can't `Add` if the thing *does* exist.
- The only way to ensure you comply with both of the above is to first `Delete` the `UIAppFonts` key.